# What does it mean for the storage for an object to be reused in Java?

Tags: java, garbage-collection, specifications

In [§12.6](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se5.0/html/execution.html#12.6) of The Java Language Specification, it says:

> The Java programming language does not specify how soon a finalizer
>   will be invoked, except to say that it will happen before the storage
>   for the object is reused.

What does it mean for the storage of an object to be reused?

Do I need to worry about this happening to my objects randomly at runtime (e.g: something overwrites an object while I'm using it)? If so, how can I prevent this?

Comment: the object has to have SOME memory allocated to it for it to exist... that'd be the storage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What does it mean for the storage of an object to be reused?
>
> Do I need to worry about this happening to my objects randomly at
>   runtime (e.g: something overwrites an object while I'm using it)?

The semantics of Java don't expose such phenomena anywhere as far as I know, so I think it doesn't mean anything, it's an implementation detail, or, an "informative" comment.

In other words, this phrase:

```
except to say that it will happen before the storage for the object is reused.
```

is equivalent to saying nothing, as it doesn't have any effect on how you should implement a conforming Java compiler.

Answer (score 0):

The storage of an object is reused after the object is garbage collected, and the memory where that object used to be stored gets used for other things.

Since that only happens after the object is garbage collected, it'll never happen to objects you're still using.

Answer (score 0):

I think that by "storage" they mean the physical heap space used for storing the object. So, according to the spec, the finalizer method is guaranteed to run while the object it belongs to hasn't been overridden yet.

If you're using an object (i.e. having a normal reference to it), it's not eligible for garbage collection at all, so you don't have to worry about it.

Answer (score 0):

Think of Java "heap" storage as a bunch of chalkboards (or "blackboards" or "whiteboards" or whatever, depending on how old you are and where you were raised).

When you create an object you "claim" one of those chalkboards for your use and write your object's data onto it.  To keep track of it, you tape a piece of string to the corner of it, and hold that string in your hand.  You call that piece of string in your hand a "reference".

You can then create a second object (claim a different chalkboard), write a name on it, and tape your end of the first piece of string to the second chalkboard next to that name.  That name is a field in the object and it references the first object you created.

So long as you have a piece of string that you can follow from one chalkboard to the next to the next to get to the most distant chalkboard you're still using, you can read what you've written on that distant chalkboard.

If you no longer want one of the chalkboards, remove the piece of string between it and either your hand or wherever on another chalkboard you may have taped it.  (This is setting the reference null.)

When a chalkboard no longer has any strings leading to it, it can be erased by the janitor and made available to others who need chalkboards.  When he does this he'll remove the strings leading away from that chalkboard to any others, and they will also get erased if no other strings reach them.  (He'll also carefully figure out if, eg, there are two chalkboards that are only tied to each other, with no other strings reaching them.  Those will be erased as well.)

A "finalizer" is a sheet of instructions you can tape to the side of the chalkboard.  Just before the janitor erases a chalkboard, he'll read the instructions on that sheet and perform whatever operations are requested.

Comment: I'm confused. What does "heap" have to do with anything? Is Java one of those languages like C where when you do something it actually just translates into machine code so you should be thinking of it in terms of what all possible outcome machine code might be? As a user of Java why/when should I care about the concept of "storage for an object being reused"?

Comment: @Dog: You should never care about that concept in Java, and the only point of the JLS section you cite is to say that "you don't need to worry about when storage for an object gets reused, even when you're using `finalize`."

Comment: @Dog - You care about the storage for an object being reused because if it wasn't reused you'd rapidly run out.  And Java programmers, through their programming style, can rather dramatically affect how much storage gets used, and how easily/quickly it's recycled.  (But that has relatively little to do with finalizers.)

Answer (score 0):

> Do I need to worry about this happening to my objects randomly at runtime (e.g: something overwrites an object while I'm using it)?

No you don't.

In simple terms, the objects will ONLY be overwritten if the GC knows that there is *no possible way* that your (pure Java) application can use them *ever again*.

---

Details:

The storage for your objects is only reused AFTER they have been garbage collected and finalized.  And an object will only be garbage collected AFTER all *reachable* references to it have been lost / overwritten / forgotten.  And if there are no reachable references to an object, your application cannot use it: - it doesn't know about the object any more.

In fact, it is a bit more complicated than that, because there are different "shades" of reachability.  For instance, an object that is waiting to be finalized is "phantom reachable", and it is possible for the finalizer to "resurrect" the object again.  But unless you are writing classes that override `finalize()` you don't need to know about this.  The think to remember is that only *unreachable* objects have their storage reclaimed, and it is a logical impossibility for a pure Java program to see the state of an unreachable object.

Comment: What does "object being overwritten" mean? Is this defined in the spec? e.g: can an object be overwritten by a boolean? can an object be overwritten by half of another object? can part of an object be overwritten?

Comment: @Dog - 1) intuitively, it means that the memory locations that previously were used to hold the object are reused for some other purpose.  2) No. 3/4/5) Moot.  By the time the object's memory is overwritten you can't access it anyway.  It has already ceased to exist.